# CONCAT_WS() for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I emulate MySQL's [CONCAT_WS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function in SQL Server?

This function is similar to [`CONCAT()` function in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) except that it adds a separator between non-NULL items:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS('; ', a, b, c, d) AS bar
FROM foo
ORDER BY id;
```

```
| ID | BAR        |
|----|------------|
|  1 | a; b; c; d |
|  2 | b; d       |
|  3 | a; d       |
|  4 |            |
```

([MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18a72c/1))

Comment: I've asked this question in order to answer it myself and make the info available to anyone. (Sorry if there's already a proper question I couldn't find.) I'll be glad to upvote/accept other answers with better tips.

Answer (score 26):

SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later has a [native `CONCAT_WS` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

For older versions, we can use a couple of tricks:

- To skip `NULL` values: [COALESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.90%29.aspx/css)
- To avoid trailing separator: add it before every item, remove the first one afterwards with e.g. [STUFF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

He's a [working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e266/1):

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  a VARCHAR(50),
  b VARCHAR(50),
  c VARCHAR(50),
  d VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c, d) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c, d) VALUES (NULL, 'b', NULL, 'd');
INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c, d) VALUES ('a', NULL, NULL, 'd');
INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c, d) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

```sql
SELECT id,
STUFF(
    COALESCE('; ' + a, '') +
    COALESCE('; ' + b, '') +
    COALESCE('; ' + c, '') +
    COALESCE('; ' + d, ''),
1, 2, '') AS bar
FROM foo
ORDER BY id
```

```
| ID | BAR        |
|----|------------|
|  1 | a; b; c; d |
|  2 | b; d       |
|  3 | a; d       |
|  4 | (null)     |
```

The purpose of `STUFF(..., 1, 2, '')` is to remove the initial separator (`2` is the separator length in our case).

This should work on SQL Server 2005 (and possibly earlier versions).

*Note: unlike the original `CONCAT_WS()`, our version returns `NULL` when all items are `NULL`. I honestly think it's a better choice but it should be easy to change anyway.*

Comment: I think CONCAT_WS is available since 2017 or 2019. Didn't know about `STUFF` function.

Comment: This has a problem though. It will always add whitespace at the end/beginning when one of the columns is null.

Comment: @Konrad Could you please elaborate on the whitespace issue? This question was quite time ago but I believe my test case already covers that :-?

Comment: e.g. when you concatenate 2 varchar columns/strings and one column is empty then there will be redundant space at the beginning/end. So it's necessary to wrap this call in RTRIM(LTRIM to get the correct result.

Comment: but it's also the case with CONCAT_WS

Comment: so CONCAT_WS should be wrapped with RTRIM/LTRIM as well. This is important when you concatenate columns with person names for example, first name, middle name, last name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576847/how-to-combine-first-name-middle-name-and-last-name-in-sql-server

Comment: @Konrad I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's only a problem when string in one column is empty like ''. When it's null it's not a problem.

Comment: so it's good to add trim or check for empty just to be extra safe

Comment: @Konrad Alright... You're using `NULL` and `''` as synonyms; they aren't. SQL handles them very differently in every level. (IMHO, empty strings is something that deserves special handling at application level—to prevent it from happening in the first place.)

Comment: Absolutely not using NULL and '' as synonyms. I just pointed out an example where it won't work. And adding RTRIM,LTRIM handles empty strings. I just said that it works for NULL but it doesn't for an empty string :)

Comment: @Konrad Sorry then. I possibly misunderstood *It will always add whitespace at the end/beginning when one of the columns is null.*

Answer (score 8):

Another approach would be to [use a FOR XML subquery](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7feba/4) like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  bar = STUFF(
    (
      SELECT '; ' + v
      FROM (VALUES (a), (b), (c), (d)) AS v (v)
      FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
    1, 2, ''
  )
FROM foo
ORDER BY id;
```

On the one hand, this looks certainly more complicated than a series of COALESCE calls. On the other hand, this is closer to the prototype in that the delimiter is only specified once.

The syntax used requires at least SQL Server 2008+, but if the VALUES constructor is changed to

```
SELECT a UNION ALL
SELECT b UNION ALL
SELECT c UNION ALL
SELECT d
```

the query will also run in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps in situations where I couldn't upgrade SQL Server to 2017 or later, and JasperReport doesn't provide a smart way to concat strings while skipping nulls.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from  **SQL Server 2017** you could use built-in [`CONCAT_WS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775030.aspx):

> **CONCAT_WS**
>
> Concatenates a variable number of arguments with a delimiter specified in the 1st argument. (CONCAT_WS indicates concatenate with separator.)
>
> ```
> CONCAT_WS ( separator, argument1, argument1 [, argumentN]… )
> ```
>
> **Treatment of NULL values**
>
> CONCAT_WS ignores the SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL {ON|OFF} setting.
>
> If all the arguments are null, an empty string of type varchar(1) is
>   returned.
>
> Null values are ignored during concatenation, and does not add the
>   separator. This facilitates the common scenario of concatenating
>   strings which often have blank values, such as a second address field.
>   See example B.
>
> If your scenario requires null values to be included with a separator,
>   see example C using the ISNULL function.

So you could use your initial query:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS('; ', a, b, c, d) AS bar
FROM foo
ORDER BY id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbdf630fa4e4cbc072dd32fe6d19c45f)**

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server 2012 you can simplify the accepted answer by replacing plethora of `COALESCE` with single [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql):

```
WITH tests(a, b, c, d) AS (
    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION
    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL,  'd' UNION
    SELECT NULL, NULL,  'c', NULL UNION
    SELECT NULL, NULL,  'c',  'd' UNION
    SELECT NULL,  'b', NULL, NULL UNION
    SELECT NULL,  'b', NULL,  'd' UNION
    SELECT NULL,  'b',  'c', NULL UNION
    SELECT NULL,  'b',  'c',  'd' UNION
    SELECT  'a', NULL, NULL, NULL UNION
    SELECT  'a', NULL, NULL,  'd' UNION
    SELECT  'a', NULL,  'c', NULL UNION
    SELECT  'a', NULL,  'c',  'd' UNION
    SELECT  'a',  'b', NULL, NULL UNION
    SELECT  'a',  'b', NULL,  'd' UNION
    SELECT  'a',  'b',  'c', NULL UNION
    SELECT  'a',  'b',  'c',  'd'
)
SELECT a, b, c, d,
STUFF(CONCAT(
    '; ' + a,
    '; ' + b,
    '; ' + c,
    '; ' + d
), 1, 2, '') AS cat
FROM tests
```

```
a    | b    | c    | d    | cat
-----+------+------+------+-----------
NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
NULL | NULL | NULL | d    | d
NULL | NULL | c    | NULL | c
NULL | NULL | c    | d    | c; d
NULL | b    | NULL | NULL | b
NULL | b    | NULL | d    | b; d
NULL | b    | c    | NULL | b; c
NULL | b    | c    | d    | b; c; d
a    | NULL | NULL | NULL | a
a    | NULL | NULL | d    | a; d
a    | NULL | c    | NULL | a; c
a    | NULL | c    | d    | a; c; d
a    | b    | NULL | NULL | a; b
a    | b    | NULL | d    | a; b; d
a    | b    | c    | NULL | a; b; c
a    | b    | c    | d    | a; b; c; d
```

Comment: One of the main drawbacks to this approach is if the value is an empty string and not `null`.

Comment: [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) does not skip over empty strings so does this.

Comment: For sure. I just mean in general. The most complete approach would be to wrap the value in an `IIF` to avoid trailing characters (semi-colon in this case).

Comment: To get the same result with empty strings (for this or CONCAT_WS) there is a handy NULLIF() function.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with FOR XML PATH. 
You can use a union (UNION ALL) instead of VALUES; this has the added value that it still works on SQL-Server 2005 (we still have to support it in our company), and you can remove NULL values.

```
DECLARE @in_SearchTerm1 nvarchar(100) 
DECLARE @in_SearchTerm2 nvarchar(100) 
DECLARE @in_SearchTerm3 nvarchar(100) 
DECLARE @in_SearchTerm4 nvarchar(100) 

SET @in_SearchTerm1 = N'a'
SET @in_SearchTerm2 = N''
SET @in_SearchTerm3 = N'c'
SET @in_SearchTerm4 = N''

SELECT 
    COALESCE
    (
        STUFF
        (
            (
                SELECT ' / ' + RPT_SearchTerm AS [text()]
                FROM 
                (
                                  SELECT NULLIF(@in_SearchTerm1, N'') AS RPT_SearchTerm, 1 AS RPT_Sort 
                        UNION ALL SELECT NULLIF(@in_SearchTerm2, N'') AS RPT_SearchTerm, 2 AS RPT_Sort  
                        UNION ALL SELECT NULLIF(@in_SearchTerm3, N'') AS RPT_SearchTerm, 3 AS RPT_Sort 
                        UNION ALL SELECT NULLIF(@in_SearchTerm4, N'') AS RPT_SearchTerm, 4 AS RPT_Sort 
                ) AS tempT 
                WHERE RPT_SearchTerm IS NOT NULL 
                ORDER BY RPT_Sort 
                FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE 
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
            ,1
            ,3
            ,N''
        )
        ,N''
    ) AS RPT_SearchTerms
```

Note the use of nvarchar - stop using varchar already. 
You also have to order it, in order to preserve sequence.

---

So what does this do:

Goal:
Take the 4 search terms inputed in 4 separate filters in a report. 
Display these 4 search terms in the report concatenated by `' / '`. 
There should not be a `' /  / '` if a search term is empty. 
It should be displayed in sequence, that is term1/term2/term3/term4, and not e.g. term4/term2/term3/term1.

How to:
So you take the 4 search terms into a union, and add a sort value to preserve order .

You select the search terms and the separator from the union (separatur + null = null)

```
SELECT ' / ' + RPT_SearchTerm 
FROM (UNION OF SEARCH TEMRS) AS tempT
```

Order it by RPT_Sort

Now select all the values (separater + text) in tempT into one XML file (`FOR XML`), where all values are XML-elements with an empty-tagname (`PATH(N'')`, and select the values XML-text (`AS [text()]`) (aka element.innerXML).

get the result of that as XML-element (`TYPE`) and retrieve the innerText string of that XML-element (`.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)')` )  (aka XML-decode).

Finally, remove the leading ' / ' (`STUFF(var, 1,3, N'')`)

This is in principle exactly the same as

```
CONCAT_WS(' / ', @in_SearchTerm1, @in_SearchTerm2, @in_SearchTerm3, @in_SearchTerm4)
```

Now add nullif,

```
CONCAT_WS(' / ', NULLIF(@in_SearchTerm1, '') , NULLIF(@in_SearchTerm2, ''), NULLIF(@in_SearchTerm3, ''), NULLIF(@in_SearchTerm4, ''))
```

and you're there.

This is how you're still able to do CONCAT_WS in SQL-Server ...

Comment: Is this different from Andriy M's answer? (Sorry, I hadn't looked at this in three years and I don't have my mind in full shape.)

Comment: @Álvaro González: I landed from google at a certain answer. Unfortunately didn't scroll up, so I didn't see it. As to difference: Yes, it uses nvarchar, which is better, because it actually works with all languages ))) Also it uses NULLIF, which means empty strings get removed (not just null values). This makes more sense, IMHO. And for beginners that don't understand what Andriy meant by UNION ALL, this is probably better. So I'm not deleting the post.

Comment: Fair enough. As about empty strings, I think the whole concept is flawed and they should have never reached high level languages (we don't have empty numbers or empty dates, do we?) but since they're actually there I don't think it's technically correct to handle them as NULL (even though Oracle does) but that's mostly a matter of opinion and is not too related to the question itself.

Comment: I've finally taken some time to review your code and (not being a T-SQL expert) I'm afraid I cannot figure it out. It isn't clear to me how to inject the table into your query or what role those hard-coded `@in_SearchTerm...` variables play. If you have the time I'd appreciate an update. Thank you!

Comment: @Álvaro González : It may be a bit late, but added explanation for you.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old post but i come the same issue.

> i simply use CONCAT() function for this.

i have address lines saved in individual fields and i wanted to join all lines to create address.

i found that CONCAT() function can handle NULL and replaces it with empty string.
also if anything plus NULL is NULL.

so i used regular CONCAT() function and add space at the end of each address line so if that line is NULL then combine output is null

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(Address01 + ' ', Address02 + ' ', Address03 + ' ', Address04) AS Address 
FROM myTable
```

Comment: Interesting... The only issue is that when `Address04` is `NULL` and at least of the previous ones is not you'll then get a bogus trailing separator, won't you?

Comment: Yes, but we can trim it

Comment: If the separator is concatenated at the beginning of the strings instead of the end, then there won't be an issue with trailing space.

`CONCAT(Address01, ' ' + Address02, ' ' + Address03, ' ' + Address04) `