# What is SQL Server function to concatenate with separator

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am looking for  SQL Server equivalent of [MySQL concat_ws](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to concatenate strings with separator. I could not find one, is there a single function in SQL server to achieve this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/19432370/1741542

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no real equivalent (even the referenced answer is not exactly equivalent).  You would normally add the separators between each value:

```
select A + ',' + B + . . .
```

One primary difference is that `concat_ws()` will skip NULL arguments, but `+` will not.  You could emulate this behavior with:

```
select stuff((coalesce(',' + A, '') + coalesce(',' + B, '') + . . .
             ), 1, 1, '')
```

Of course, this doesn't convert the values to strings, as `concat_ws()` does.  So, a closer version is something like:

```
select stuff((coalesce(',' + cast(A as varchar(255)), '') +
              coalesce(',' + cast(B as varchar(255)), '') +
              . . .
             ), 1, 1, '')
```

You can apply the same fixes to the referenced answer:

```
SELECT id,
       STUFF((SELECT ';' + cast(v as varchar(255))
              FROM (VALUES (a), (b), (c), (d)) AS v (v)
              WHERE v is not null
              FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
             ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
             1, 1, ''
            )
FROM foo
ORDER BY id;
```