# How to combine first name, middle name and last name in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

you can refer the below queries to get the same-

## 1

```
select FirstName +' '+ MiddleName +' ' + Lastname as Name from TableName.
```

## 2

```
select CONCAT(FirstName , ' ' , MiddleName , ' ' , Lastname) as Name from 
  TableName
```

## 3

```
select Isnull(FirstName,' ') +' '+ Isnull(MiddleName,' ')+' '+ Isnull(Lastname,' ') 
from TableName.
```

Note: Point 1 query return if all columns have some value if anyone is null or empty then it will return null for all, means Name will return "NULL" value.

To avoid the point number 1, you can use point number 2 or point number 3 -

We can use `IsNull` or `CONCAT` keyword to get the same.

If anyone containing null value then ' ' (blank space) will add with next value.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I have posted the question with an answer.

Comment: @RiteshYadav I think you mean, you posted your attempts, and you are looking for better answers. Answers should not be included in the question. Your attempts are flawed. If there is no middle name, your text will have 2 spaces between firstname and lastname. If there is no firstname, your text will start with a space

Answer (score 26):

- Using a combination of `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` will strip any white-space on each end.
- `CONCAT` to append the name segments together
- `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` with an empty string

*Formatted for readability*

```sql
SELECT 
    RTRIM(LTRIM(
        CONCAT(
            COALESCE(FirstName + ' ', '')
            , COALESCE(MiddleName + ' ', '')
            , COALESCE(Lastname, '')
        )
    )) AS Name
FROM TableName
```

Comment: What happens if FirstName is null?

Comment: If any are `null` then `COALESCE` transposes them to an empty string in this case, or whatever the second argument is.

Comment: It might be worth noting that string concatenation works different with the + operator than with the CONCAT function:
null + *anyString* == null 
vs.
CONCAT(null, *anyString*) == *anyString*

Comment: In Postgres, `FirstName + ' '` gives an error on the `+`:  `ERROR:  operator does not exist: text + unknown`. (...and yes I realize this is for SQL Server, but it sure got me close for Postgres as well)

Comment: The + sign in phpmyadmin mysql is causing the error "Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ' '"

Answer (score 16):

Replace function removes two character white-spaces while concatenating First, **Middle** and Last Name.

SQL2016 and above compatible code

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(FirstName+' ',MiddleName+' ',LastName+' '),'  ',' ') 
AS EmployeeName
FROM dbo.Employee
```

SQL SERVER 2017 Compatible code:

```
  SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ',FirstName,MiddleName,LastName),'  ',' ')AS 
  EmployeeName FROM dbo.Employee
```

Comment: The SQL2016 solution works well for me, however there is no reason to add the trailing space after LastName and it ends up in the result. Just remove that.

Comment: **replace** in both examples is not doing anything, unless the one of the names actually has an extra space. In this case the **replace** is actually a problem causing the names to merge

Answer (score 4):

Just Do A replaces for Double Space with Single Space on #3 and it should work as expected

```
SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(
    ISNULL(FirstName,' ') 
    +' '+ 
    ISNULL(MiddleName,' ')
    +' '+ 
    ISNULL(Lastname,' '),
    '  ',' ')))
FROM TableName
```

Comment: it's been very useful. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select CONCAT(FirstName , " ", MiddleName, " ", LastName  )as Name from 
  TableName
```

by using `""`  my issue is solved

Answer (score 1):

This handles the case that...

- any name field could be `NULL` or blank,
- names could have double or more spaces at the middle of them (not like using `REPLACE`), and
- compatible with even SQL Server 2008 (at least from what I've tested):

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.FirstName)), '') + ' ', '') +
             ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.MiddleName)), '') + ' ', '') +
             ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.LastName)), ''), '')) AS name
FROM TableName T
```

- `NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.FirstName)), '') + ' '` evaluates to `NULL` if the name is blank because anything concatenate with `NULL` is `NULL`. Otherwise, it returns a trimmed name with a trailing space.

  - [`LTRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql) and [`RTRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql) removes the spacing at the start and the end of the value. If you are using SQL Server 2017 or later, you can also use [`TRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) instead.
  - [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal. In this case, we return a null value if the name is empty.
- [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) replaces `NULL` with the specified replacement value. The first parameter is only `NULL` if the name is `NULL` or blank, then replace with an empty VARCHAR, which means there is no extra space introduced when concatenating with the rest of the name fields.
- The outer `RTRIM` removes the last potential space if the last name is `NULL` or blank, but not first name or middle name.

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me.

If you have SqlServer 2014 (or Lower).

```
Select
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(ISNULL(FirstName,''),' ','')
    +' '+
    REPLACE(ISNULL(MiddleName,''),' ','')
    +' '+
    REPLACE(ISNULL(LastName,''),' ','')
,'  ',' ') As [FullName]
From [Table];
GO
```

The benefits of using this code are:

- it removes (NULL) and (Empty) names.
- names contain more than one space (at the beginning) or (at the end) or (between the letters of the name) are removed.

---

Edit 1: (2023-02-13)
I found a better answer (more readable),
I will just write it here for future reference.

using --> Internal IF (IIF)

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        CONCAT(
            TRIM([FirstName])
            ,
            IIF([FirstName] + [MiddleName] IS NULL, '', ' ')
            ,
            TRIM([MiddleName])
            ,
            IIF([MiddleName] + [LastName] IS NULL, '', ' ')
            ,
            TRIM([LastName])
        )
    ,'  ',' ') As [FullName]

FROM <[Table]>;
GO
```

The benefits of using this answer are:

- `CONCAT()` --> will replace all `ISNULL()` as it returns `''` (Empty string) if the passed parameter is `NULL`, and also it implicitly converts passed parameters to string and merges them.
- `IIF(<condition>, true, false)` --> i use it to check left & right before writing `' '` (space) between names.
- Note: `TRIM()` was introduced in Sql Server 2016 (and later).

Comment: TRIM([MiddleName]) , IIF([MiddleName] IS NULL AND [FirsrName]+[LastName] IS NOT NULL, '', ' ')

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you looking for:

```
select Isnull(FirstName,'') +' '+ Isnull(MiddleName,'')+' '+ Isnull(Lastname,'') from TableName
```

That is, when any name is `null` it will be replace with empty string `''`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rtrim(concat(FirstName + ' ', MiddleName + ' ', LastName + ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

A sure-fire way to list names with or without a Middle Name AND prevent convoluted function evaluations, is to deal with double spaces themselves and nothing else:

```
select REPLACE(FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + Lastname
               , '  ', ' ') as Name
from TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

select concat(firstname ,' ',middlename, ' ',lastname ) as fullname from xyz

Answer (score 0):

Replacing empty string and removing leading and trailing whitespaces

```
SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(FirstName+' ',MiddleName+' ',LastName+' '),'  ',' ')) 
AS EmployeeName FROM dbo.Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name , ' ', last_name) as COMBINED_NAME
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly u need to combine two values from diff tables!

```
select surname 
    from cd.members
union
select name
    from cd.facilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as full_name from patients

patients is the table name which has the first name and last name column. here I want to combine the first and last names in the new column, which is the full name so I'm using CONCAT. Concat is an SQl server function that takes a variable number of string arguments and concatenates (JOIN) them into a single string. Quote marks for making a single space between first and last names.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Concat(FirstName,' ', isnull(MiddleName+' ',''), LastName) as fullname from Tablename
```