# Concatenating first, middle and last names in SQL when some people don't have middle names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return a concatenation of first, middle, and last name columns in a database table `Authors`. However some Authors just have `NULL` as a value in the middle name column.

As a result, my code below, for Authors with only a first and last name, returns the first name, followed by two spaces, followed by the last name.

I'd like to avoid this, and only ever have 1 space between each name, regardless of whether they have a middle name or not.

Is there a simple way of achieving this that I'm missing?

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', MiddleName, ' ', Lastname)
FROM Authors
```

EDIT:

I did find this, which involves `RTRIM` and `COALESCE`. Not sure if there's a simpler solution or if this is the best way:

[How to combine first name, middle name and last name in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576847/how-to-combine-first-name-middle-name-and-last-name-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server and assuming your middle names cannot be empty, then you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(FirstName, ISNULL(' '+ MiddleName + ' ', ' '), Lastname)
FROM Authors
```

Comment: how `ISNULL' function will return single space?

Comment: If MiddleName is NULL it will evaluate to ISNULL(NULL, ' ') which will return an empty space.

Comment: Hey. Thank you. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server but this works! I've gotten quite a few answers on here surprisingly, so I'll check those as well. This seems to be the simplest way however.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select concat(FirstName, case when MiddleName is not null then concat(' ', MiddleName) else null end, concat(' ', LastName))
from Authors;
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your question I am assuming that all the authors have `FirstName` and `LastName`.

So, you can write your query using `case`.

```
SELECT
      CASE 
           WHEN (ISNULL(MiddleName, '') <> '') THEN CONCAT(FirsName, ' ', MiddleName, ' ', Lastame)
           ELSE CONCAT(FirsName, ' ', Lastame)
      END AS FullName
FROM Authors
```

`ISNULL` is a function which will check if your value is `null` or `empty`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `CONCAT_WS`:

```sql
CONCAT_WS(' ',FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)
```

Otherwise, if you're on an old(er) version of SQL Server, use `STUFF` remove the first delimiter:

```sql
STUFF(CONCAT(' ' + FirstName, ' ' + MiddleName, ' ' + LastName),1,1,'')
```

Comment: Confused as to why all these answers all got downvotes. Though a comment isn't required, downvoting them all would really explain why the user feels that ***all*** these answers aren't helpful.