# How do you get the first and last name from the ID?

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I am making a system for my work and I am struggling on figuring out how to take the Employee_ID and get the First and Last name of the employee and then take the first and last name and combine it to be just the full name.

I have already figured out how to convert first and last name to full name using

```
Create proc FullName
as
begin
select concat(concat(fname, ' '),lname) FullName
from Employees
end
```

Comment: What's the question? What's wrong with your posted code - what did you expect and what actually happened? How is C# related - there's nothing posted about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine first name, middle name and last name in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576847/how-to-combine-first-name-middle-name-and-last-name-in-sql-server)

Comment: Are you just looking for the `WHERE` clause in SQL?  It's not really clear what specifically you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an SQL-related question but since you are using concat, you can also select the field distinctly as shown above.

Whereas, adding the where clause limits your result to only the specified ID.

The question in the query is where your ID goes depending on which method you are using and the target DBMS

```
Create proc FullName @employeeId int
as
begin
select concat(concat(fname, ' '),lname) FullName, fname, lname
from Employees WHERE Employee_Id = @employeeId

end
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, it is far better using named params/variables in SQL Server, it far easier to read. For example `WHERE id = @EmployeeId`

Comment: "_you can also select the field distinctly as shown above_". It is very unlikely that an stored procedure named `FullName` is intended to get also the first and last names.